# Getting a folder including all subdirectories and files as they are using GULP

Tags: gulp, gulp-zip

I am trying to zip a folder and all its subdirectories and files included using gulp-zip. I have tried these codes:

```
gulp.src('wp_plugins/zion_slider/')
    .pipe(zip('zion_slider.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wp_boilerplate/inc/plugins/'));
```

This one just takes the folder not the subdirectories or files

```
gulp.src('wp_plugins/zion_slider/**/*.*')
    .pipe(zip('zion_slider.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wp_boilerplate/inc/plugins/'));
```

This one take only files and subdirectories not the parent.

As I want to zip the parent folder and the subdirectories and files, none of the above work for me.

Can anybody suggest anything, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the base directory in `gulp-src`

```
gulp.src('wp_plugins/zion_slider/*', {base: './'})
    .pipe(zip('zion_slider.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wp_boilerplate/inc/plugins/'));
```

**EDIT**

Right you are, I misunderstood and had the wrong glob. Here try this one. The output is a zip file named `zion_slider.zip` that contains the `zion_slider/` folder with all files and sub dirs. You can play around with the paths to get what you want. For example if you want the .zip file to *not* include the zion_slider folder you can use `{base: wp_plugins/zion_slider }`

```
gulp.task('default', () => {
    gulp.src('wp_plugins/**/*', {base: './wp_plugins'})
        .pipe(zip('zion_slider.zip'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

**EDIT**

```
    gulp.src('wp_plugins/zion_slider/**')
    .pipe(zip('zion_slider.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wp_boilerplate/inc/plugins/'));
```

This also works.

Comment: it takes 'wp_plugins/zion_slider/all_the_files' instead of 'zion_slider/all_the_files'. plus this cannot take the files under subdirectories.

Comment: Looks like the second snippet from my question also works. I had some other issues with the code. So, I am removing it from question and adding it to answer.